# To get root access using on android phone and unlocking the bootloader

Tags: android, python-3.x, ubuntu, bootloader

How can I get root access on android phone without having to use the SDK tools..is it possible to try it with python and  Ubuntu terminal...I have searched online it only suggests other tools like Fastboot which also comes with SDk , ADB...

Can anyone give me some guidelines where to start?
and what python packages will be helpful? Kivy framework how helpful it will be..as it is cross platform...PS:I want to learn about Mobile Forensics

Answer (score 0):

I am now working with emulator from android Studio it is safer and convenient this way as using a emulator by default root access is given. ADB comes with lots of features and it is also easy to connect python scripts with the virtual device. My host machine is Windows OS I don't even need to use VM.